# Excel parent child hierarchy

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have some data and I need to create a hierarchy of data.

prdCode is the child and the ID;

prdParent shows  the parent of the data;

prdLevel show what level the data must be at. 0 is the top.

I need the result to be go from this:

> Child | Parent
>
> Data A | Data B1
>
> Data A1 | Data A
>
> Data B1 | Default

to this:

> ```
> Data B1
>
>  Data A
>
>   Data A1
> ```

I need a solution preferably using formula.

The tree can go 5 levels deep

[Data image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsXBh.png)

Comment: What would be the expected OUTPUT using the attached sample data and any Criteria to Match Child to Parent ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following program does what you want.  The solution is broken up into 4 sections (constants, helper function, function, and trigger).  See notes at the bottom for important information

### Constants

I declared one constant to limit the number of rows that I am inspecting.

```vb
Const ROWMAX As Integer = 12
```

### Helper Function

I created a helper function that indents text based on the level.

```vb
Function Indent(level As Integer) As String
    Dim result As String
    Dim i As Integer

    result = ""
    i = 1
    Do While i <= level - 1
        result = result & "  "
        i = i + 1
    Loop

    Indent = result
End Function
```

### Main Function

This is a recursive function that starts at the root of the tree (as specified by the caller) and prints out that tree.

```vb
Function Printout2(level As Integer, parentID As String) As String
    'Hard-coded range to columns A-G and rows 1-1000.
    Dim origData As Range
    Set origData = Worksheets(1).Range("A1:G" & ROWMAX)

    'Where we store our result from this call.
    Dim result As String

    'Convenience variable to use during looping operations
    Dim currentID As String
    Dim currentName As String

    If level < 1 Or level >= 6 Then
        'If there should be a blank line between "groupings", then replace "" with vbnewline
        Printout2 = ""
    Else
        For i = 1 To ROWMAX
            If origData.Rows(i).Columns(4).Value = parentID Then
                currentID = origData.Rows(i).Columns(2).Value
                currentName = origData.Rows(i).Columns(3).Value

                result = result & Indent(level) & currentID & " " & currentName & vbNewLine
                result = result & Printout2(level + 1, currentID)
            End If
        Next i

        Printout2 = result
    End If
End Function
```

### Trigger

Finally, I added a trigger using an ActiveX control (button).  Note that I have to specify the first parent, which is the string `"-1"`.  You can rewrite this code to find all rows with `prdLevel = 0` if you have multiple root Parents, then call `Printout2` for each root.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Worksheets(2).Range("A1").Value = Printout2(1, "-1")
End Sub
```

### Output

Here was my output from executing this program.

```
1087 Consumer Electronics
  17422 Retail Data Checks
    17591 Consumer Electronics Total Retailing
  21342 Consumer Electronics (Retail)
    16467 In-Home Consumer Electronics
      16485 Home Audio and Cinema
      23711 Home Video
    16500 Portable Consumer Electronics
    16521 In-Car Entertainment
    17545 Computers and Peripherals
```

### Misc

Some final notes:

- Assumes all data is on the first worksheet, starting at cell `A1` with the headers
- Assumes the results will be placed on the second worksheet, in cell `A1`.
- Current code assumes there is only 1 root Parent entry.  If there are multiple, change the trigger (or write another function) that find all the roots and invokes `Printout2` once for each root.
- I did **NOT** rely on the `prdLevel` column as it may be wrong, and solely relied on the relationships between Parent and Child.  If there is a row that has an incorrect `prdParent` value, then it won't be printed in the results.